# Como aplicar o `visited` num `a` usando javascript?

Tags: javascript

Imagina que eu tenha um CSS:

```
a {
   color: blue;
}

a:visited {
   color: red;
}
```

E um HTML:

```
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

Assumindo que eu não tenha conhecimento de qual o `color` está sendo usado, e não possa manipular o histórico do navegador, como posso aplicar o `visited` num `a`?

Isso é, como posso fazer algo assim:

```js
a = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
a.href = "https://" + Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '');
a.visited = true;
```

```css
a {
     color: blue;
  }

  a:visited {
     color: red;
  }
```

```html
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

O resultado desejado seria que o `a` estivesse com o estilo de `visited`.

Comment: Por curiosidade, por quê necessita disso? Isso não altera a usabilidade da aplicação indicar como visitado um link que o usuário não visitou?

Comment: Você está criando um link aleatório e quer que ele tenha o efeito de `a:visited` mesmo não tenha sido visitado? Não seria mais fácil aplicar o mesmo efeito a determinado link em vez de mudar o "estado" dele?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu tenho uma aplicação em Go que usa o Sciter, o Sciter por si permite manipular este tipo de coisa. Eu uso o `active`, `visited` (...)  e outras propriedades, por exemplo se a pessoa clica num botão e tal. Agora, estou querendo também possibilitar "compilar" para Javascript, usando o GopherJS, ele funciona, mas eu não consigo manipular esse tipo de coisa, assim tudo que usa essas propriedades ficaram quebradas. :(

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam O link aleatório é só para o navegador não salvar como "visitado", se clicar. Mas, sim, eu quero que fica com `visited` mesmo que ele não tenha visitado. Se houver como pegar o estilo do :visited e aplicar, daria o mesmo resultado desejado. O que eu quero é que o estilo de visited fosse aplicado num momento qualquer. Se houver como copiar o estilo do visited e aplica-lo seria suficiente. O eu quero, no fim das contas, é evitar mudar o código existente, reutilizando tudo e apenas "passando para Javascript".

Comment: fiz uns testes e a única coisa que poderia responder é como não funciona, acredito que seletores como `:visited`, `:hover` entre outros não possam ser acessados (pelo menos não facilmente)

Comment: Depois eu pensei que o `visited` poderia ser um problema de privacidade, daria para saber quais sites foram visitados. Mas, alguma maneira de "write-only" seria ainda útil. Acho que pelo jeito irei mudar tudo para alguma classe do tipo `.active`, `.visited` (...) e aplica-lo ao elemento, mas não era algo que queria. :(